# Nested top level each in handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, each

Given this context

```
{
  letters: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  numbers: ['1', '2', '3']
}
```

How would I produce

```
a1
a2
a3
b1
b2
b3
c1
c2
c3
```

In essence,

```
{{#each letters}}
{{#each ../numbers}}
what to put here?
{{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I am specifically using https://github.com/sunng87/handlebars-rust, however this in theory has very close to feature parity, so how it would be done in handlebars.js should be compatible.

For reference, my actual usecase is C++ code generation. And the question is largely about accessing this `this` propery of an internal loop. Right now my code looks like

```
{{#each variant}}
{{#each ../typearg}}{{#if @first}}template <{{/if}}{{this}}{{#if @last}}>{{else}},{{/if}}{{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

However for some reason, this outputs

```
template <>
template <>
```

when I am expecting it to output

```
template <T>
template <T>
```

The object as is relevant and being passed to it is in the form

```
{
    typearg: [ 'T' ],
    variant: [{ }, { }]
}
```

Comment: Looks like a nested `#each` loop, with `letters` on the outer, would do it.

Comment: Is there a way to do it maintaining the nested construct?

Comment: Please add `handlebars-rust` as a tag, especially if you're creating a bug report based on this question.

Comment: I added it for you, since I don't believe you have the ability to do that with new tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way out would be is to create a new handlebar helper which would return you the `html`.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('multi_list', function(context, options) {
  var html = "";
  var letters = options.hash.letters;
  var numbers = options.hash.numbers;

  for (var i=0; i< letters.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j <  numbers.length; j++) {
        html += '<li>' + (letters[i] + '' + numbers[i] + '</li>';
    }
  }

  return html;
});
```

And you would call the helper

`{{#multi_list letters numbers}}`

If you want to still iterate using the existing `each` helper, then you can use 
`{{this}}` or `{{./this}}` to access the innermost loop value and

`{{../this}}` to access the outermost loop value which is one level higher

```
{{#each variant}}
    {{#each ../typearg}}
        {{#if @first}}
            template <
        {{/if}}
            {{this}}
         {{#if @last}}
            >
         {{else}}
            ,
         {{/if}}
     {{/each}}

      {{../this}}

 {{/each}}
```

Comment: I've added my actual usecase to the OP, which is C++ code generation. I have a lot more templating to do in reality inside the nested loop than simply outputting the letters

Comment: The you could move all the logic to inside the helper if that is the case. You can write up any complex logic in JS inside the helper. It is always better to abstract out the complexity from the `HTML`. That is the primary reason for the helpers in handlebars.

Comment: I would have assumed that accessing values inside nested loops was fairly basic functionality for a tepmlating language. Otherwise there is little value in supporting nested loops at all

Comment: @LucilleBlumire If you still want to do in the `HTML` side, you could do that instead I think. To access the value of the innermost loop you could do `{{this}} or {{./this}}`. And to access the value of the outermost loop you could do `{{../this}}`. How does the complete `each` code block look like ?

Comment: Ah, trying that out on a handlebars simulator it appears I've found a bug in handlebars-rust, I'm going to go and open an issue, id you want to post an example doing {{this}} and {{../this}} as an answer I'll mark it as accepted, as that's what I was looking for

Comment: @LucilleBlumire Glad you found something. Updated the post .